# How to keep zero values in an array of duplicates?

Tags: java, arrays, duplicates, integer

I'm still struggling to get the right input for this code where I need to remove duplicates and return the result. I get everything right until this:

- given array `[100, 0, 3, 4, 4, 562, 100]`
- the answer should be `[100, 0, 3, 4, 562]`
- but what I get is `[100, 3, 4, 562]` (So it removes the 0)

Is there any way I can just add to my code since I'm not allowed to use any built-in functions, ArrayList, List, Set etc, so just implementing my own solution and functions.

```
public static int[] removeDuplicates(int[] input) {
    int[] withoutDubs = new int[input.length];
    int pos = 0;
    for(Integer element: input) {
        if(!checkIfInArray(withoutDubs, element)) {
            withoutDubs[pos] = element;
            pos++;
        }
    }
    int[] result = new int[pos];
    for(int i = 0; i < pos; i++) {
        result[i] = withoutDubs[i];
    }
    return result;
}

public static boolean checkIfInArray(int[] input, int number) {
    if(input == null) {
        return false;
    }
    for(Integer num: input) {
        if(num == number) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`withoutDubs` is filled with 0s by default when it is first instantiated.

Therefore `checkIfInArray(withoutDubs, 0)` returns `true` even if `0` appears only once in the array.

You can pass an index to `checkIfInArray`, so that it doesn't search all the `withoutDubs` array. It should only check indices `0` to `pos - 1`.

```
public static boolean checkIfInArray(int[] input, int last, int number) {
    if(input == null) {
        return false;
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < last; i++) {
        if(input[i] == number) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

and change the method call from

```
checkIfInArray(withoutDubs, element)
```

to

```
checkIfInArray(withoutDubs, pos, element)
```

Comment: Thank you, that was an excellent idea actually; never thought of it

Comment: @TheFoxterGirl well, it's similar to what you are already doing when you build the `result` array - you only take elements of `withoutDubs` array from index `0` to `pos - 1`, and ignore the rest.

Answer (score 1):

Since you can't *use any built-in functions*, then you can implement them yourself: a kind of `contains` and `grow` methods from the `ArrayList`. And since the `int[]` array contains *zeros* by default, you can use the `Integer[]` array instead.

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] arr = {100, 0, 3, 4, 4, 562, 100};
    Integer[] noDuplicates = new Integer[0];

    for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (!contains(noDuplicates, arr[i])) {
            noDuplicates = grow(noDuplicates);
            noDuplicates[j++] = arr[i];
        }
    }

    // output: [100, 0, 3, 4, 562]
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(noDuplicates));
}
```

```java
static boolean contains(Integer[] arr, int val) {
    for (Integer el : arr) {
        if (el != null && el == val) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

```java
static Integer[] grow(Integer[] arr) {
    Integer[] target = new Integer[arr.length + 1];
    System.arraycopy(arr, 0, target, 0, arr.length);
    return target;
}
```